# How to pass more arguments to a signal in Pyside2?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

Hope you are fine.

I populated a table with images and it behaves like I want for the most part, except when I connect the cell to a cellClicked signal.

Lets say I have this function

```
def print_cell (column,row):
    print(column,row)
...
table.cellClicked.connect(print_cell)
```

This works as intended, prints a (column, row) pair when the cell is clicked, but i need a bit more than this. My intended function needs more than the column and row pair.

I need something like this:

```
def print_cell(column, row, max_column_count)
    print(row*max_column_count + column) #I need to convert to array to load files.
```

I dont understand how this can be done as cellClicked only gives me column and row. I have tried more than a few things but nothing seems to work, I would like your clean slate suggestions as I might have understood wrong.

Edit: providing a bit more of minimal code.

```
# import 
# The imports we are using are custom made except for os, sys and math, but they include everything we need. I will use the name custom_module when instancing this classes, but they are basic a shortcut to PySide2 stuff.

def count_files(*args):
    pass
#This counts the number of files given name prefix or extension inside a defined folder. It returns a unsigned integer with the total.

def print_cell(row,column):
    print(row,column) #this is the function I want to improve.

class PyDialog(custom_module.QDialog, custom_module.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, path, parent=None):
        super(PyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
    
    ext = '.png'
    path = 'files'
    prefix = 'icon'

    file_count = count_files(path,ext)
    max_column_count = 4 #This is hardcoded at the moment as this number will depend of other factors.
    row_count = math.ceil(float(file_count)/float(max_column_count))
    
    self.window=custom_module.dotui.load_ui(path, self)
    
    table = self.window.img_table
    
    table.setColumnCount(max_column_count)
    table.setRowCount(row_count)

    for index in range(file_count):
    
        column, row = divmod(index,max_column_count)
        
        icon_label = custom_module.QLabel()
        icon_pixmap =custom_module.QPixmap(path+prefix+str(index)+ext)
        icon_label.setPixmap(icon_pixmap)
        table.setCellWidget(column,row,icon_label)
    
    table.cellClicked.connect(print_cell)


    self.window.show()
    


if __name__ == '__main__':

   dialog = PyDialog('path')
```

A couple of further comments:

Yes, for now the external functions are not part of a class, as pointed out in the comments.

I stripped the code from a lot of functionalities regarding the look of the table, but this might be enough to diagnostic the problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example, so we can see what data is available. My gut feel is that `print_cell()` should be part of a class and therefore be able to access that class' properties, and that `self.max_column_count ` is one of those properties.

Comment: Sorry for not doing so first, I can't share the code and I was trying to edit it but published to see if what I showed might be enough. I will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: The question was updated @couka THanks

Comment: "This is hardcoded at the moment as this number will depend of other factors." *what* factors? Do those factor depend on other aspects defined in the class instance? Is there a specific and important reason for which those functions are outside the class?

Comment: I would like to make max_column_count dependent of the resize of the windows and the size of the icons (from a dropbox menu). Unfortunately, Im just starting the code so I wanted to focus on the functionality itself and I was just writing the functions. There is no specific reason for having those outside other than 'I was starting and this is one of the first UI I make'

Comment: @pythonenthusiast the fact that this is the first UI you're making doesn't count, it's more related to the class/instance concept. From what you describe, it's very unlikely that you'll ever use that function for something else than from (and *for*) the instance, so having it outside doesn't give you any benefit; on the contrary, since that function should use a value that will be specific to the instance, having it as an instance method will allow you to access all instance members, including that value.

Comment: Besides that, what is `custom_module` and what are those `QDialog` and `QMainWindow` you're inheriting from? Are they PyQt's QDialog and QMainWindow? If that's so, be aware that that class constructor is *wrong*: Qt doesn't play well with multiple inheritance of its classes, and even if it was supported, it doesn't make any sense to inherit from *both* QDialog and QMainWindow, which have *very* different scope, behaviors and purposes. OTOH, if one of them is *not* a Qt class (such as a pyuic generated file), you should *not* use existing Qt names for that.

Comment: I cant disclose most of that info you are asking, I wanted to respect the integrity of the code needed to ask the question but I cant share it, but taking into account somebody else already answered precisely seems to indicate it doesnt matter. I value your enthusiasm and I hope your answers help somebody else, but I got lost on them as you didnt take into account I dont have the experience as this is my first UI, im learning a lot of stuff. I recommend taking that into account next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to pass extra data:

```
def print_cell(table, row, column):
    columnCount = table.columnCount()
    print(row * columnCount + column)
```

lambda:

```
table.cellClicked.connect(lambda row, column: print_cell(table, row, column))
```

partial:

```
table.cellClicked.connect(functools.partial(print_cell, table))
```

Comment: Thanks! this is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass more arguments with the signal. In general, the additional information should be accessible through the class members. In your particular case, you have two options:

1. To use the hard coded `max_column_count`, e.g. `print(row*self.max_column_count + column)`

or

2. (preferred) To get the column count of the `table`, e.g. `print(row*self.table.rowCount() + column)`

Comment: Havent tested it but this makes sense now. I guess that I can access any other relevant variable through the class members, for example a prefix and stuff like it. Thanks.